# tcpdump traffic capture for remote machines

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I was trying to capture the traffic of my website

I opened a  remote Machine , logged into my website .

Then from my windows machine , opened putty instance  logged into that remote Machine

and issued the following command under putty

```
sudo tcpdump -n -s 1500 -X src host  mywebsite.com
```

Please tell me why it is not dumping any data ??

I was surprised because the same command was working on Ubuntu Desktop Terminal but not inside GNU/Linux ??

Comment: Is it giving any error message? Also try selecting the interface using `-i`.

Comment: What happens if the *first* thing you do is log into the remote machine over Putty and start tcpdump, and *then* connect to your Web site on the remote machine?

Comment: Does the remote machine have more than one network interface it could use to connect to your Web site?

Answer (score 0):

host need single quote 'host mywebsite'

Comment: No, it doesn't - tcpdump will take all the arguments after the flags, glue them together with spaces between them, and use that as the filter.